# disable specific item on ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I created a `SimpleAdapter` and I am using that for my `ListView`.

Here is what I did:

```
JavaList<IDictionary<string, object>> menuItemNames = new JavaList<IDictionary<string, object>> ();

JavaDictionary<string, object> sideItem1 = new JavaDictionary<string, object> ();
sideItem1.Add ("text", "Home");
sideItem1.Add ("icon", Resource.Drawable.menu_icon_home);

JavaDictionary<string, object> sideItem2 = new JavaDictionary<string, object> ();
sideItem2.Add ("text", "Sign Out");
sideItem2.Add ("icon", Resource.Drawable.menu_icon_signOut);

JavaDictionary<string, object> sideItem3 = new JavaDictionary<string, object> ();
sideItem3.Add ("text", "Help");
sideItem3.Add ("icon", Resource.Drawable.menu_icon_help);

menuItemNames.Add (sideItem1);
menuItemNames.Add (sideItem2);
menuItemNames.Add (sideItem3);

string[] sideMenuFromArr = { "text", "icon" };
int[] sideMenuToArr = { Resource.Id.textSideMenuItem, Resource.Id.imgViewSideMenuItemIcon };

// this is where I created the adaper
SimpleAdapter sideMenuListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (context, menuItemNames, Resource.Layout.item_menu, sideMenuFromArr, sideMenuToArr);
```

After this, I just applied this list to my `ListView`.

```
this.absHomeSideMenuList.Adapter = sideMenuListAdapter;
```

If I want to disable one of the item at some point, what would I do?
I want to keep it in the list but remove the click event AND change the text color to gray to make it look disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `BaseAdapter#isEnabled(int position)` method to specify which list item is enabled/disabled. It should use underlying data kept by adapter for particular list item to decide. You will have to subclass `BaseAdapter` or any of its decendants to do that. To specify look of list item depending of it's state override `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method. When your underlying data kept by adapter has changed and you want your list view connected with adapter to reflect that call `BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am very new to this so can you give me an example by any chance?  I understand about the position but I don't think it's necessary for me. When I do have to disable an item, I would know the actual position since my list is very limited.  What do you mean by subclass `BaseAdapter` ?

Comment: By subclassing `BaseAdapter` I mean creating a class which inherits from it. You should really take some time to understand key concepts of listviews and adapters. They are important in Android programming. Here I'm giving you a link to post which will show you how to create very simple listview with adapter [ListView using BaseAdapter](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/) You can base your solution on information from this post and extend it by overriding `BaseAdapter#isEnabled(int position)` method.

Comment: Afterwards you can further expand your knowledge by reading [Using lists in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Ok so I created a new class where I extended `BaseAdapter`, and I have `override view GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup Parent)` and other required `override`.  But how does `public boolean isEnabled(int position)` help me?  If I call that from my activity and I pass `2` for `position`, what will it actually do?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work that way. `isEnabled` is called when your listview wants to render new list items and asks adapter for them. Then `isEnabled` tells list view whether list item should be enabled or not. So when something happens in your app that should change the state of a given list item you should change that list item underlying data kept by adapter and call `BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`. List items will be rerendered reflacting their new state.

Comment: I am sorry. I am having hard time understanding this.  I looked into that as well and that will work if my `ListView` is changing. `NotifyDataSetChanged()` will change the view if necessary but how would it affect the enabled or disabled state of that item? For example: when my activity is starting, I ALWAYS want the first item to be disabled. How does `NotifyDataSetChanged()` affect the actual `ItemClick` event?

Comment: What decide whether particular list item is enabled or disabled (and thus clickable or not) is in fact it's underlying data kept by adapter. On the base of underlying data adapter's `isEnabled` method decides what to return for every list item (true for enabled or false for disabled). Adapter pass that information to listview. By calling `notifyDataSetChanged` method you give adapter an order "Tell listview that my dataset has changes so it should get the new one".

Comment: So what to do  to always have first item disabled? Set its underlying data kept by adapter in such a way that `isEnabled` method will always return false  for it.